# Disable migration report in VisualStudio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, migration, projects-and-solutions

### SCENARIO

I normally download a lot of 3rd party source codes to examine them and learn new things.

### PROBLEM

I'm using VS2013, and everytime that I open an old Visual Studio solution it automatically updgrades the project and then shows an html report on my default web-browser.

### QUESTION

Is there an **automated** way to disable the reporting? (not the migration operation, just the reporting)

I didn't found any option in Visual Studio to disable the reporting, but maybe could look into other approach in case of that thing is set via registry to hack it to fully disable the web-browser reporting or open the report file in notepad for example?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to disable the upgrade log from opening when opening an old solution in a newer version of Visual Studio (that isn't from a backwards compatible version).

However, if you open the developer command prompt and run:

```
C:\dev\proj>devenv /upgrade thesolution.sln
```

Then it will do the upgrade without causing the upgrade log to actually open.

Then you just have to wait for VS to load. I'm not sure which is the lesser of two evils here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for this issue. You need to edit your `.csproj` file.

Open your .csproj file and find below element:

```
<FileUpgradeFlags>0</FileUpgradeFlags>
```

Remove value of this flag and leave it empty and you will not get migrate report. In case value is not 0, any value you have to delete.

Comment: This action keeps my Visual Studio from crashing, but replaces the crash with the error message:
` : error  : The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: If it is so then edit the csproj file again using notepad and set the value to 0. If this stops your crashing problem then let me know. If it is not then the problem is something else.